# MySQL query trigger showing error after variable assign query

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger

I have added the following query but it doesn't work, after I added set x line. Please help me fix this query

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT;
  SET x = SELECT donation_id FROM wp_give_donationmeta ORDER BY wp_give_donationmeta.meta_id DESC LIMIT 1;

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status= 'Sponsored' WHERE ID= x;
END
```

Comment: What error you are gettting?

Comment: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT donation_id FROM wp_give_donationmeta ORDER BY wp_give_donationmeta.meta_' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

You could the update  just using a single query

```
UPDATE wp_posts S
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT donation_id 
  FROM wp_give_donationmeta 
  ORDER BY wp_give_donationmeta.meta_id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) t 
SET post_status= 'Sponsored' WHERE ID= t.donation_id;
```

assuming you are creating valid trigger  then you could

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE wp_posts S
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT donation_id 
    FROM wp_give_donationmeta 
    ORDER BY wp_give_donationmeta.meta_id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) t 
  SET post_status= 'Sponsored' WHERE ID= t.donation_id;
END;
```

Comment: I need to  add this query to trigger

Answer (score 1):

Try to use <kbd>[EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php)</kbd>

```
BEGIN

   UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET post_status= 'Sponsored' 
   WHERE EXISTS( SELECT donation_id 
                 FROM wp_give_donationmeta 
                 WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_give_donationmeta .donation_id);
END
```